# Docker Unable to find user: no matching entries in passwd file for OpenJdk11

Tags: java, docker, openjdk-11

I'm trying to build and run the image with a non-root user and keep getting the error: "unable to find user test: no matching entries in passwd file."

Here's what my Docker file looks like:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim

RUN addgroup --system test
RUN adduser --system testuser --ingroup test

USER test:testuser

COPY build/libs/abc-0.0.1.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "app.jar"]
```

I already tried searching for the error and looked at other places but none seems to work for me. Could someone help me out here? I know I can run it with the root user but I don't want to or if there's another Openjdk11 image that I could use to make it work then that's also fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with the line `USER test:testuser`

You are creating a usergroup called `test` and a user called `testuser` but in your `USER` statement in the Dockerfile you specify `test:testuser`, which is not the correct order. It must be like `USER testuser:test`

> USER user:group
>
> or
>
> USER UID:GID

See the Dockerfile reference [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user).